# CABasicAnimation with UINavigatonController and custom animations goes wrong

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, customization, cabasicanimation

**Here below you can see the result of my code. Please note that the second time when I press in the Back Button the animation is not working.**

Best Regards

[image]

I have tried for hours to understand what is the trouble with my animation, but I can't find the source of the problem. I have been looking around the internet for an answer without success. So,  this is my problem.

I put the animation to `finish()` if the transition goes more than 50% of the `view.bounds.width` and `cancel()` otherwise

This is my steps

1. Handle the Animation to less than 50%
2. The animations goes back
3. Press the **Back** button in the `UINavigationItem` and the animation runs to fast

This my code in the **Animator**

```
class Animator: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    private var pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = 0
    private var isLayerBased: Bool  { operation == .pop  }

    let animationDuration = 1.0

    weak var storedContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?

    var interactive: Bool = false
    var operation: UINavigationController.Operation = .push

    func handlePan(recognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer)
    {
        // This part is only for get percent of the translation in the screen with the finger

        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: recognizer.view!.superview!)
        var progress: CGFloat = abs(translation.x / recognizer.view!.superview!.bounds.width)
        progress = min(max(progress, 0.01), 0.99)

        switch recognizer.state {
        case .changed:
            update(progress)

        case .cancelled, .ended:
            if progress < 0.5 {
                cancel()
            } else {
                finish()
            }
            interactive = false

        default:
            break
        }

    }

    override func update(_ percentComplete: CGFloat) {
        super.update(percentComplete)

        if isLayerBased {
            let animationProgress = TimeInterval(animationDuration) * TimeInterval(percentComplete)
            storedContext?.containerView.layer.timeOffset = pausedTime + animationProgress
        }
    }

    override func cancel() {
        if isLayerBased {
            restart(forFinishing: false)
        }
        super.cancel()
    }

    override func finish() {
        if isLayerBased {
            restart(forFinishing: true)
        }
        super.finish()
    }


    private func restart(forFinishing: Bool)
    {
        let transitionLayer = storedContext?.containerView.layer
        transitionLayer?.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        transitionLayer?.speed = forFinishing ? 1 : -1
    }


    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)
    {
        if interactive && isLayerBased {
            let transitionLayer = transitionContext.containerView.layer

            self.pausedTime = transitionLayer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
            transitionLayer.speed = 0
            transitionLayer.timeOffset = pausedTime
        }
        self.storedContext = transitionContext

      if operation == .pop {
        let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)!
        let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)!

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
        animation.fromValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: CATransform3DIdentity)
        animation.toValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: CATransform3DMakeScale(0.001, 0.001, 1))

        animation.duration = animationDuration
        animation.delegate = self

        fromVC.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        fromVC.view.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)

      } else if operation == .push {

        // The Push Animation
        // ...
      }

   }
}


extension Animator: CAAnimationDelegate {

    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        if let context = self.storedContext
        {
            print("COMPLETE TRANSITION & ANIMATION STOP")
            context.completeTransition(!context.transitionWasCancelled)
        }
        self.storedContext = nil
    }
}
```

That was my animator `class`. In my **MainViewController** the only interesting code is this:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    let animator = Animator()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

        animator.operation = operation
        return animador
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, interactionControllerFor animationController: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        if ! animator.interactive {
            return nil
        }
        return animador
    }

}
```

And in my **DetailViewController** I have this

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var animator: Animator?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if let masterVC = navigationController!.viewControllers.first as? ViewController {
            animador = masterVC.animador
        }
        let pan = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPan(recognizer:)))
        pan.edges = .left
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
    }

    @objc func didPan(recognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if recognizer.state == .began
        {
            animador?.interactive = true
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
        animador?.handlePan(recognizer: recognizer)
    }
```

Comment: This might be completely irrelevant but I just wanted to mention, I have found it much easier to track what's going on in custom animations to use UIViewPropertyAnimator instead of UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition. Your animations do not seem to me to call for CABasicAnimation and CAAnimationDelegate; the latter especially can really get you tied up in knots because the animation _retains its delegate_, which has often caused me great trouble and confusion. Doing things the straightest simplest easiest way is usually the best policy.

Comment: Mmm.. good comment. But anyway, I am intrigue with this trouble what can be